# Android: explanation of different types of permissions in the manifest?

Tags: java, android, permissions

I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me make sense of this - what is the difference between the following types of permissions that can be listed in the manifest? This list is by no means exhaustive, but it helps illustrate the variety. I'd also appreciate knowing whether I only have to worry about **android.permission.SOME_PERMISSION** types for the upgrade to android M or whether other types could also be relevant to the new permissions model and could potentially "break" after the upgrade?

Types:

```
android.permission.SOME_PERMISSION

com.google.android.[some_provider].permission.SOME_PERMISSION

my.package.name.permission.SOME_PERMISSION
```

Edit: perhaps "break" is a bad word to use here - I mean a permission that could potentially be revoked by the user and therefore lead to a crash/notification when the user uses the app.

Comment: What makes you feel like the permissions model may _break_ from one version to another?

Comment: @dotvav as I understand it, under M the user can revoke permissions from the app causing it to potentially crash/show a notification when those permissions are needed. The question is whether this could break the functionality of features that use permissions that are not of type android.permission.SOME_PERMISSION